# Sound coming out of headphones and speakers!

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, soundcard

I'm new at Ask Ubuntu, but not at Ubuntu itself! So, I have a Dell Latitude D520 with Ubuntu 12.04.4 on it. When I plug in my headphones, sound comes out from the headphones and the speakers!I tried to enable automute, but then my speakers didn't work. It's kinda getting on my nerves because I can't listen to my dubstep... Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I can help. i had the similar problem. this actually has nothing to do with whatever software or OS you are using. I had to take my computer apart and tighten my headphone jack. If its not that then i dont know what it is

Comment: But, before upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04.4, it worked perfectly.

Comment: if its not a hardware issue then im not sure.